# vs 2013 mvc routing not working after change to cshtml view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a very strange problem. I am new to the mvc world coming from web forms and i am trying to understand its concepts. **Using the MVC template in vs 2013** (premium), I have built a project. In order to see how things work:

1. I create a new controller 'IndexController' and put it in the folder .../Controllers/IndexController.cs
2. I create a new View for this controller 'Index.cshtml' and put it in the corresponding folder: .../Views/Index/[@] Index.cshtml
3. Then I change the routing so that the default routing will now point to this IndexController and not to the default HomeController

Here is my routing table:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                
            defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "GetIndexPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You can see that I am using 'GetIndexPage' as the default action instead of 'Index' (I'm playing around and see how it works)
Whenerver I make a change in the Index.cshtml (say I add a simple markup and hit 'Run' I always receive the error message

```
Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
```

Looking at the address bar I see that the browser is looking for the resource 'localhost:xxx/Index/Index' instead of 'localhost:xxx/Index/GetIndexPage'. To solve this problem, I go in the IndexController and put a breakpoint inthe line

```
return View(...);
```

Now I hit 'Run', after stopping at the breakpoint, every thing works perfectly. So it is not a problem of routing since the page is displayed after this breakpoint trick. Visual Studio seems to mess up with the deployment to the IIS Express I am using after I have made a change to the cshtml view. The problem does not occur when I make a change in the code behind of the controller. I don't know where to look at...I have spent this whole night trying to find a solution in Google and stackoverflow...I don't want to reinstall the whole visual studio. Any help, any hint to a certain direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a view named `'GetIndexPage.cshtml` in the Views/Index folder?

Comment: no I have the view Index.cshtml

Comment: So are you doing return `return View("Index");`?

Comment: yes exactly with the full path

Comment: Whats `[@]` in `/Views/Index/[@] Index.cshtml`?

Comment: this is just the way it appears in the solution explorer in vs. the actual name is of course just Index.cshtml

Comment: I just recreated your controller and view and cant reproduce the error. Are you sure its `return View("Index");` (what did you mean by _"exactly with the full path"_?)

Comment: I mean "~Views/Index/Index.cshtml"

Comment: There must be something messy between vs at iis express since it is working after several attempts of clean rebuild and run

Comment: Not sure what changes you may have been making but may have been a cache issue. Note its not necessary to use the full path unless you want a view from a different controller.

Comment: @seyaobey have you tried `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Comment: @Badik where would I put this code? on the UnknownAction exception handler?

Comment: I just saw that when I run my project directly from my local IIS server ( i select my application from the default web sites tree node and hit 'Browse *80:http) I can immediately see my changes, every thing works perfectly. So the problem is visual studio debugging related. Somehow it messes up when a change occurs in the .cshtml file. It fails to update it immediately to the server. This problem occurs only in a mvc project. Web forms work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials I discover that mvc framework wants the action and the view (that this action returns) must have the same name. In my case this is what has worked:

1. route configuration:

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "IndexPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```
2. IndexController:

   ```
   public class IndexController : Controller
   {
      public ActionResult IndexPage()
      {
        return View();
      }
   }
   ```

You can see that route action has same name with method of controller: IndexPage
And finally create a view with name IndexPage.cshtml

With this configuration when I make a change in the cshtml file it is immediately reflected in the browser and there is not the error reported above.

I just want to have a confirmation if this is indeed the way things must be set up with the mvc approach. (thanks with your help)